# How to make scroll-based animations using JQuery work with Bootstrap 3 modals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble understanding the visibility of the Bootstrap modal divs and when or why they show as visible even when hidden.

Normal divs on the page, outside of the modal, work perfectly with the code I have written.

...

I wrote some JS and CSS to say: if any element with `.animation-element` is in the view of the window, then add `.in-view`, if not, remove `.in-view`. It should be pretty simple, and it is, except for the divs inside the modal that have `.animation-element` ALWAYS show as having the `.in-view` class.

...

```
var $animation_elements = $('.animation-element');
var $window = $(window);

function check_if_in_view() {
  var window_height = $window.height();
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

  $.each($animation_elements, function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
    var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
    var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

//check to see if this current container is within viewport
if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
    (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
  $element.addClass('in-view');
} else {
  $element.removeClass('in-view');
}
  });
}

$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$window.trigger('scroll');
```

and

```
.animation-element {
  opacity: 0;
}

.animation-element.in-view {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

Even if the div with the `data-target` for the modal does not show `.in-view` because it's out of the screen view, any div inside the modal with the class `.animation-element` has the class `.in-view`. I have placed all of the modal divs at the very bottom of the page and they still show the same result.

Here is a code pen example: http://codepen.io/ethanethan/pen/MbbyoE

Comment: maybe try giving a margin-top: -1000px to the modals. Not sure and may not be the best solution

Comment: That still didn't work. I think it has to do with my JS more than anything. Sorry I am still relatively new with JS and JQuery, but I know it's not with CSS.

Comment: np. If you can set up a working example somewhere(jsfiddle, codepen etc.), people will get a more clear picture and be able to help more

Comment: Ok @MandeepJain I added a code pen to the main area. http://codepen.io/ethanethan/pen/MbbyoE

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also trigger your check_if_in_view() function when modal is clicked/toggled. Lucklily bootstrap's js provides events for modals (check "events" section here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
So it would be:

```
...
$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  check_if_in_view();
});
$window.trigger('scroll');
```

where #myModal could be changed to .modal to work for whole project and also be aware that on this event only .animation-element that are inside modal should be checked, so you would need to change this piece of code further more.